# Add text in the latest row entry, at the specific column in swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to add a text on a single column to the latest row; Column (A,B,C) & row (1,2,3) let's say A1 = baby, B1= boy is already exist, and C1 is where I want to insert data.

Here is what I've done and I was able to sort it out and insert the text, however it creates a new row to add the new entry, the idea is to use the same row but add the entry on of the column (A3).

here is what I got so far

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Facebook")
let newentry = twitter

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
query.whereKey("add", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
query.limit = 1

if error == nil
{

let foundObjects: [PFObject!] = objects!
for object in foundObjects

{
self.useradd.text = object["add"] as? String
print(object["add"])


}
```

Comment: Your question is about `parse.com`, not database and parsing . Please use appropriate tags to improve audience to your post.

Comment: Also you have assign the query constraints before the block `findObjectsInBackground`. Inside the block you manipulate the data. After you are finished, you can call `saveInBackGround` method. Read up the documentation of parse which is extremely thorough and very helpful. This is very basic stuff, the update query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set your parameters on your query after you run it, that doesn't make any sense! You have to do this before trying to find the objects otherwise the parameters won't matter.